# uservoice - How to resolve Exceeded API Limit?

Tags: uservoice

I am stuck. I get the exception

> Exceeded API Limit

when I try to get data from *user voice*.
But sometimes it does work. How can I fix it?

I have `m.getValue()` as the `id` of the forum and `m.getkey()` as `id` of the suggestions loop (array of id suggestion list). So I tried this:

```
Collection comments = client.getCollection("/api/v1/forums/" + m.getValue() + "/suggestions/" + m.getKey() + "/comments.json");
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question please